# Is there a way to zoom into the next node in the 'setSelected' list?

Tags: python, nuke

In The Foundry NukeX I'm trying to find list of nodes of same kind and zoom into each node one after the other of the `.setSelected` nodes.

To be clear I'm trying to create a Python code thats behind    `Edit` -> `Search...` menu or hotkey <kbd>/</kbd> in NUKE.

With the below script it only zooms into the first node of the `.setSelected` list.

Is there a way to increment the zoom to next set of nodes every time I execute this code?

```
for w in nuke.allNodes('Transform'):
    w.setSelected(True)
    xC = w.xpos + w.screenWidth()/2
    yC = w.ypos + w.screenHeight()/2
    nuke.zoom(3, [xC, yC])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **nested `for-in`** loop to make iterations inside a desired class.

Here's a how your code should look like:

```
import nuke

for node in nuke.allNodes('Grade'):
    node.setSelected(True)

    for id in nuke.selectedNodes():
        xCoord = id.xpos() + id.screenWidth()/2
        yCoord = id.ypos() + id.screenHeight()/2
        nuke.zoom(5, [xCoord, yCoord])
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, this code doesn't work in Nuke 12, what do you guys think is the issue? it just stays on the first selected node, doesn't zoom into the next selected node.

Comment: Hi @venkat! It definitely works in NUKE 11, 12, 13... The problem is: you're seemingly using a Non-Commercial version. Consider, the Non-Commercial mode has a `10-node limit` in Script editor... So NUKE returns `None`.

Comment: Hi @andy, no no im using NukeX and pasted the code as-is in the editor, here is the screenshot  https://ibb.co/n801r8P

The same code worked before, i don't know why it's not doing now.

Comment: Are you running it on Mac?

Comment: I tried both mac and windows, but the screenshot I sent you is from Mac

Comment: Miracles.......